# SQL Server CXPACKET timeout

Tags: sql-server

We've got SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.4206.0), by default there is no restrictions for parallelism - any count SQL wants. And it didn't lead any problems... Till now.

For another feature there were written query that unexpectedly raised timeout exception in our application. I was deeply surprised when it was successfully executed with setting up maximum threads per query to 1. Yes, 6 seconds for query is not so good, even accounting to most of time was spent for fetching, but it's far away from 3 minutes timeout!

By the way, executing this query with SQL Server Management Studio works all the time despite of parallelism settings. It seems that something wrong with connection to database, but all other queries works fine, even which much harder then that one.

Our application is built on ASP.NET Core 3.0 (don't know if it matters), database connection is made using `System.Data.SqlClient v4.8.0`. All I could determine is that there are so much tasks created for this query:

[image]

I've tried to watch for execution in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` (thanks google). I'm not sure I got it right, but it seems that tasks with `context_id` 0-8 is blocked with those who have `context_id` 9-16 and vise versa. Obvious example of deadlock, isn't it? But how can SQL Server manage threads to make it without my "help"? Or what am I doing wrong?

Just in case some inappropriate answers:

- I won't turn parallelism off (set maximum threads per query to 1) as solution because of some heavy queries in our application;
- I don't want to raise `Cost Threshold for Parallelism` setting because I'm afraid of same problem with another query (guess, a heavier one). So I just want to determine real cause;
- Optimizing the query isn't considered (anymore), as according to actual execution plan I can't make it faster - there are enough indexes for it. But I'm ready to rethink after some really weighty arguments.

So, **my question is**: why does parallelism that I didn't ask for spoil the query execution? And how can I avoid that?

Comment: "Cost Threshold for Parallelism" should be 50 regardless, but that's not your problem...

Comment: are your statistics up to date?

Comment: @MitchWheat, did you mean to say "not unusual"?

Comment: `CXPACKET` waits are a natural biproduct of parallelism. I suggest you first look at query and index tuning so that SQL Server doesn't need to throw threads at the query to make it run faster. Upload the actual plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) if you need help with that.

Comment: What you're seeing is not a deadlock (that would inhibit progress altogether); you're seeing parts of the query that can't be effectively parallelized and must execute serially, so that other tasks are waiting for that part to finish before proceeding. The engine is generally eager to use parallelism but often unable to use it effectively. Unless you fancy rewriting the engine yourself, you will have to start considering some approaches you now reject. If all else fails, forced execution plans can be used to change the behavior for one query without rewriting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true sometimes the engine chooses to use parallel execution (or not to use) which leads to worse performance.

You do not want to control the server option and the cost as you are not sure how this will reflect to other queries, which is understandable.

If you are sure, your query will be execute better without being handle in parallel, you can specify the option just for it using [query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15) - MAXDOP like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

It's easy and you can rollback if needed. Also, you are not affecting other queries.

You are saying that:

> Optimizing query isn't considered (anymore), as according to actual execution plan...

The execution plan is sometimes misleading. As a start - you can save your execution plan and open it with `SentryOne Plan Explorer` - it's free and can give you a better look of what's going on.

Also, if a query is execute for either 3 seconds or 6 minutes, there must be something wrong with it or may be the activity of your database. If it is executed fast in the SSMS always, maybe the engine is using the correct cache plan. I thing it's better to share the query itself and to attach the two plans (serial and parallel) and spend more time tuning it.